# Ассоциативное дерево списка объектов javascript

Tags: ооп, javascript, dom

Есть фрейм, а так же дерево с тегами объектов, находящихся в этом фрейме. Дерево получается в результате перебора всех объектов фрейма и записи их тегов в виде:

```
<div>DIV
<div>P</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>UL
<div>LI</div>
<div>LI</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Каким образом лучше связать объект с его значением в дереве при переборе объектов фрейма? Хочется узнать как сделать это максимально просто и эффективно.

К примеру: кликаем на тег в дереве и изменяем стиль соответствующего объекта, тем самым выделяя его. И наоборот, кликаем по объекту во фрейме и выделяем соответствующую запись в дереве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
tree = function ( root, printer ){
  var stack = [],
      curr = root,
      type = true;

  while( curr ){
    if ( type && curr.can_right() ){
      type = true;

      stack.push( curr );
      curr = curr.right();
    }
    else if ( curr.can_down() ){
      type = true;

      curr = curr.down();
    }
    else{
      type = false;

      curr = stack.pop();
    }
  }

  return root;
}

printer = function ( t_parent, el ){
  this.parent = t_parent;

  this.el = el;

  this.copy = document.createElement('div');
  this.copy.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  this.copy.innerHTML = el.tagName;

  //Связывание-начало
  this.copy.real = el;
  this.copy.onclick = function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    else event.cancelBubble = true;
    this.real.style.border = '5px solid black';
  }

  el.copy = this.copy;
  el.onclick = function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    else event.cancelBubble = true;
    this.copy.style.border = '5px solid black';
  }
  //Связывание-конец

  if ( t_parent ) t_parent.copy.appendChild( this.copy );
}

printer.prototype.right = function (){
  return new printer( this, this.el.firstElementChild );
}

printer.prototype.down = function ( t_el ){
  return new printer( this, this.el.nextElementSibling );
}

printer.prototype.can_right = function ( ){
  return ( this.el.firstElementChild !== null );
}

printer.prototype.can_down = function ( ){
  return ( this.el.nextElementSibling !== null );
}

t_res = tree( new printer( null, document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0] ) );

res = t_res.copy;
res.style.position = "absolute";
res.style.top = "0px";
res.style.width = "100px";
document.body.appendChild( res );
```

Comment: Можно описать способ "связывания" и соответствующие примеры или фрагменты текущего кода?

Comment: обновил ответ,  так должно быть более понятно.

Comment: В вашем коде я так и не разобрался. Но всё же в процессе просмотра мне в голову пришла идея, которая и стала отличным решением, причём очень эффективным.